# Using SQL Where clause with OR operator

Tags: sql

Is this possible with normal, non-vendor specific SQL? If not, what can one do to search two different columns?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM airpapr_base
WHERE article_content_title_en
LIKE '%google%'
OR
WHERE article_content_text_en
LIKE '%google%'
```

Comment: Lose the second `WHERE` and it should be fine

Comment: Are you trying to get a seperate count for each where clause in the same query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM airpapr_base
WHERE article_content_title_en
LIKE '%google%'
OR
article_content_text_en
LIKE '%google%'
```

Notice the lack of second `WHERE`. It should work

Relevant tutorials: [WHERE clause](http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/sqlwhere.php) (section "SQL - Where with Multiple Conditionals"), [Search conditions (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173545%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

Comment: @Jon Egerton: yep, happens :)

Comment: @wowpatrick: don't beat yourself up, it happens with everybody

Answer (score 1):

OR is simply a logical operator for combination of predicates.  It can be used in the same manner as AND:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM airpapr_base
WHERE article_content_title_en LIKE '%google%'
OR article_content_text_en LIKE '%google%'
```

If you combine AND and OR, then of course you have to be aware of operator precedence to be sure conditions are combined in the order you are expecting (or simply parenthesize everything to be certain).

Answer (score 0):

Have a go with:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM airpapr_base
WHERE 
    article_content_title_en LIKE '%google%'
    OR article_content_text_en LIKE '%google%'
```